# Displaying user information from Instagram PHP API

Tags: php, api, oauth, instagram

Excuse the super-precise question but I'm fairly new at this and could use some help. I thought I was understanding everything until I hit this roadblock.

I'm using [9lesson's Instagram PHP Oauth tutorial](http://www.9lessons.info/2012/05/login-with-instagram-php.html), which is built upon cosenary's Instagram PHP API class.

Everything is running properly but I am trying to add a line which shows the logged-in user how many followers they have.

I added this third line, copying the first two lines which already existed.

```
echo '<b>Profile Pic:</b> '.$data->user->profile_picture.'</br>';
echo '<b>Access Token:</b> '.$data->access_token.'</br>';
echo '<b>Followed by</b> '.$data->user->counts->followed_by.'</br></div>';
```

I added the last line under `$_SESSION['userdetails']=$data;`

```
$followers =$data->user->counts->followed_by;
```

Why will this not return any data, even though it is the correct name for the endpoint? I feel like I've tried every possible combination of 10 things. Any help would be great!

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($data)` and post that here?

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the Instagram API youre using.

Looks like you're getting `$data` from this call

```
$data = $instagram->getOAuthToken($code);
```

This call is meant to get an access token and it calls this endpoint

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

if you look at the [Instagram API](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/) you'll see that this call doesn't return any counts

```
{
    "access_token": "fb2e77d.47a0479900504cb3ab4a1f626d174d2d",
    "user": {
        "id": "1574083",
        "username": "snoopdogg",
        "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1574083_75sq_1295469061.jpg"
    }
}
```

With his API im not sure how to get the count.  I built an [API](https://github.com/galen/PHP-Instagram-API) (requires php 5.3+) that makes it super simple.

```
$current_user = $instagram->getCurrentUser();
$followers = $current_user->getFollowers(); //get first page of followers
$followers_count = $current_user->getFollowersCount(); //get number of followers
```

Here's an example

http://galengrover.com/projects/instagram/?example=current_user.php

Comment: Very nice library, very nice solution.